# What is the name of front-end model using React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, model-view-controller, model, frontend

I use create-react-app to initially create my project, and Redux to manage its state.
Before, I think it's the MVC model because React render the view, and when the someone using the client makes changes, the dispatcher will take the actions then send it to the store, the store using reducer to process, update a state if needed (and isn't state just the model?) and send it back to the view, , then return the updated view.

Is that right?